# aplicación web con Python- django o javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, web

Tengo una consulta: la diferencia de construir aplicaciones web usando django o javascript, o se puede hacer uso de ambos, javascript para front y python con django para el back, por allí leí que las aplicaciones web con django eran mas lentas al momento de la carga pero dan mas seguridad y permiten una fácil escalabilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras hacer amigo por ejemplo si tu proyecto requiere de una maquetado MVC que en django se utilizan otros terminos  para eso del MVC entonces utiliza django pero si es mas para la validacion de datos y interactividad en el lado front end de tu pagina web utiliza mas java script y si se puede  utilizar los dos tanto django como javascript se pueden pasar datos de django a javascript y creo viceversa lo ultimo no lo he intentado pero si amigo todo depende te digo para que lo requieras
ademas con la nueva version de django es mas facil utilizar django ya que antes se utilizaban expresiones regulares y era mas dificil pero fuera de eso hoy en dia django es una excelente alternativa a javascript bueno al meos en su mayoria